# Android: is it possible to startActivity from another class

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

Here is my code:

Class calendar_list

```
        new list_view().next(pk[position],maintype[position],this);
```

Class list_view

```
public void next(int pk,int type,Context ct){
    Intent intent = null;

    if(type==1)
        intent = new Intent(ct,text_eachview.class);    
    else if(type==2)
        intent = new Intent(ct,pic_eachview.class);
    else if(type==3)
        intent = new Intent(ct,video_eachview.class);
    else if(type==4)  
        intent = new Intent(ct,voice_eachview.class);

    intent.putExtra("ID",pk);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

My code doesn't work, I want to know why? Is this possible?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It's because your initial revision had very little information, I'll give you a +1 because you've added it now. :)

Comment: now i can't ask any question , because i got banned what can i do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that your list_view instance is not a started activity. Try to declare you next method as

```
public static void next(int pk,int type, Activity ct){
```

and to start the next activity as

```
ct.startActivity(intent);
```

(this would work given that calendar_list is an activity and calendar_list.this is a started activity (most likely the currently visible one))

Comment: thank you very much for your help , but now i got banned i can't ask the question anymore by the way thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Because Activity 'c' isn't declared in your manifest file.

Comment: Ah well it was a guess. Look in logcat, it'll tell you the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like B is also an activity. Why aren't you using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this,C.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

in your activity A?

Comment: because it is my test code , i will show you my real code soon

Comment: But B is an activity, and you're not launching it using an Intent, but you're using methods out of it? I'm not sure if that's legal?

Comment: start() is a method in B, it was called many time in B then i wanna call start() from A but i don't wanna create start() in A,  that why  !!